# Mtime timezone is different than ctime&atime, why?

Tags: timezone, stat

I used the `stat` command on a certain file and I noticed *mtime* was in a different timezone than *ctime* and *atime*,

What would cause such a thing and what is the reason that someone would do that?

I'm investigating this system so I don't know why things are configured the way they are.

- What is the cause of the timezone difference?
- How can I check if it's like that in the entire server or just some selected files.

[image: example]

Comment: [Please don't post text as images](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's almost certainly due to daylight saving.

Note that the dates in the `+0100` time zone are in January, and the `+0200` date is in the end of March. That would be just after the start of daylight saving (summer time) in the EU, for example.

Comment: i think that's the case! thank you so much for the idea, ill check some other files near that date.

Comment: @saharq if you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.